# Python: how to solve a string: "2 + 2"

Tags: python, string

so my question is: given a random string like this "5 + 5" how can I return a result in Python? 
I can't just do int("5+5").
For example:

```
op1 = raw_input("Enter first number(e.g. 2):")
op2 = raw_input("Enter second number(e.g. 2)")
operation = raw_input("Enter operation(e.g. +):")
result = op1 + operation + op2
print result
```

How do I print **4** istead of **2+2**? How do I print **8** instead of **2*4**?

Comment: Since this is obviously homework, I'll just give some hints. You need `if`/`elif` block to check which operator is being used, and convert the operands to a numeric type.

Comment: have a read about more general solution to your problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: @Wooble If this is homework, this is _stupid_ homework _if_ it basically teaches student how to use `eval()`..

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: if the assignment doesn't forbid `eval()` and require the students to use stuff they actually learned in class, then sure, it would be stupid. Building a simple calculator is hardly an uncommon programming assignment.

Comment: It actually wasn't homework. I was just wondering if it's possible to evaluate input without taking it apart and putting together into a Python friendly format (and save myself some coding!).

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to use [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
>>> eval('2+2')
4
```

This however is risky since a user may insert a virus into your code that way. The more sophisticated (and correct) answer would be to write your own parser. For example:

```
if operation == "+":
    return int(op1)+int(op2)
elif operation == "*":
    return int(op1)*int(op2)
# etc.
```

This is just a trivial example. Real parsers are far more complex. You may want to have a look at for example PLY: http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/

Comment: I wasn't the one downvoting. Just wanted to point out the mistake.

Comment: @BartvanNierop Okey dokey, fixed.

Comment: @KobiK Actually that's not true, since `ast.literal_eval` can't handle operators.

Comment: @freakish you are right, deleted.

Comment: _"may insert a **virus** into your code"_ While `eval` could lead to [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection), it seems a little bit confusing to use the word "virus" here. Especially as the OP is clearly in the process of learning "programming".

Answer (score 1):

In order to evaluate the content of a string in Python you can use the [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function:

```
op1 = raw_input("Enter first number(e.g. 2):")
op2 = raw_input("Enter second number(e.g. 2)")
operation = raw_input("Enter operation(e.g. +):")
result = op1 + operation + op2
print eval(result)
```

I have to specify that the *eval* is not safe to use in a protected-context, so don't use it when you haven't the certainty that the parameter that you are using is correct.

Comment: A down vote for what?

Comment: I didn't downvote but eval is not [safe](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), that is probably the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot let you go without a word of warning: `eval` is `evil` because it could lead to [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

---

As it is quite clear this is homework, I won't come with a complete solution. Only some clues.

First, remember than [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a *string*. Not a *number*.
In Python `+` and `*` are overladed so they do something with strings too, but not what you might expect if you come from, say a PHP background.

So, before doing calculations on the value returned by `raw_input` you first must convert them to the appropriate *type*. Here, using `int(...)`.

In a *real program* you should be prepared to deal with "bad input" from the user. For example, someone just typing <kbd>enter</kbd> or providing data that can't be converted to the proper type. This is called validating user input. And to end as I started with an advice: **never trust users inputs!**